# Graphics card memory usage in linux

Tags: linux, graphics

What tools are available to monitor graphics card memory usage in linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to know it for 3D graphics development purposes, you may want to look into something like [gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com/) or, if you only care about NVIDIA cards, you can try [NVIDIA PerfHUD](http://developer.nvidia.com/content/nvidia-perfhud).  I have not used them myself, but I would expect them to track such information.

Comment: I fixed the broken link to NVIDIA PerfHUD. However, Linux doesn't seem to be supported anymore.

Answer (score 2):

[NVIDIA PerfKit](http://developer.nvidia.com/content/nvidia-perfkit) has a linux version which allows real-time monitoring of various graphics card properties, including graphics card memory usage. Obviously, this only works for NVIDIA graphics cards, and it also requires the use of a special instrumented driver.

Comment: I fixed the broken link to NVIDIA PerfKit. However, Linux doesn't seem to be supported anymore.

Comment: That's too bad, do you know any way to make it work under Linux? Maybe using an older version of it will work?