# How to tell the graphic card memory usage?

Tags: monitoring, gpu, video-card

My application seems to be slow, but in terms of CPU and RAM, it seems that it is OK. So, I want to know how much memory of the graphic card I am using. I've seen some questions about this on SO, but they talk about Linux or NVidia. I would like to have this information for ATI cards on Windows.

Thanks.

Comment: What API are you using, OpenGL or DirectX?

Or if you are just writing a normal GUI app, this is probably not possible, but the OS probably does a good job at managing buffers so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50042/graphics-card-memory-usage-in-linux

Comment: I'm using both openGL and directX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the [OpenGL debugger](http://www.gremedy.com/)?

Comment: You are right, I've always see this software as a debugger; but it can be use as a monitor too: Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you use OpenSceneGraph in order to render scene, there is a stats monitor that shows the usage of GPU.